# Battlefield 4(PC) expansion packs, cant get into servers

Tags: battlefield-4

The issue I'm having is that, every time i try to play a multiplayer game, on most servers ill get a "legacy operations expansion pack required" or a "nightops required" etc. Now to be clear, i purchased a "league pass" or whatever you want to call it when BF4 first came out so i should own all of this already.

Even still, i click on the "get legacy operations" button and the "get nightops" button to see if theres anything i have to download but there isnt anything.

Aside from weapon kit shortcut packs, or battlepacks(gold silver etc), i own everything and the download page literally says "you own this"....

so im pretty much stuck. Not sure how to proceed. Can anyone help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to recollect how I worked around this.

When Origin shows that I have indeed purchased said expansion pack, I right-click (or click the "Play Now" button) on that expansion pack icon which opens a new browser tab for me.  At that point, joining a server works for me.